# Automatically update navigation bar with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a JavaScript file that will allow webpages to automatically have the same content that all other webpages on my site require. The problem is that the navigation bar needs to automatically add the disabled class to links that are to the webpage being viewed. I am unsure how to do this, and I can't find a good solution anywhere on the web. here is my code so far. I am concentrating on the "navigate" section

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#initiate').append('\
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" />\
    \
    <!--Style data-->\
    <!-- -- jQuery -- -->\
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom\css\purple_theme\jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" />\
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>\
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom\css\purple_theme\jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" />\
    <![endif]-->\
    \
    <!--jQuery data-->\
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>\
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>\
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>\
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>\
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/script.js"></script>\
    ');
//remember to check the pages that need to updated from being disabled
$('#navigate').append('\
    <div class="ui-widget">\
        <div style="width: 15%; display: inline-block; float: left">\
            <ul class="navbar">\
                <h4 style="color: white">Resources</h4>\
                <li id="home" title="Home Page"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>\
                <li id="beta" title="Test Out our services"><a href="beta">Beta Test</a></li>\
                <li id="alert" class="ui-state-disabled" title="Not Yet Available"><a href="#serviceAlert">Sign Up</a></li>\
                <li id="question"title="Have a question or confused? Click here"><a href="questions">Questions</a></li>\
                <li id="privacy" title="Learn about our policies to protect your information"><a href="privacy" >Privacy</a></li>\
                <li id="about" title="Learn about MHER"><a href="about">About</a></li>\
                <li id="hippa" class="ui-state-disabled" title="Coming Soon!"><a href="#comingSoon">HIPPA Blog</a></li>\
                <h4 style="color: white">Health Law</h4>\a
                <li><a href="http://thomas.loc.gov/cgi-bin/query/z?c104:H.R.3103.enr:" target="_newtab">HIPPA Law</a></li>\
                <li><a href="http://thomas.loc.gov/cgi-bin/query/z?c111:H.R.3590.as:" target="_newtab">ACA</a></li>\
            </ul>\
        </div>\
    </div>\
    <div style="width: 80%; display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px">\
        <div class="ui-widget-header" style="border-radius: 10px">\
');
 });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery `.addClass()` might be the method you're looking for. Simply add an "active" or similar class to the navigation item that's being viewed.

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: How would I do that on the condition that the webpage being viewed is corresponding to the weblink needing the class?

Comment: You could have a switch statement based off of something unique in the file, like it's title for example.

Comment: Ok I will give that a try, would I grab the title of the page by coding a variable like this: 

     var title = $('title);

Comment: You can just use document.title. :)